# How do I save org-agenda-files customizations in Doom Emacs?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, customize, doom

I am currently running Doom Emacs and using org-mode. When I try to move a file to the front of the agenda file list (C-c [), It is updating the `custom.el` file, rather than the `config.el` file.

In my `config.el` file, I have it set up like so:

```
;; set up org mode
(after! org
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org-roam/20210908114649-inbox.org" ))
)
```

Moving a file to the front of the agenda list works correctly in the current session, but because it's updating the `custom.el` file, when I restart emacs, the changes are not applied.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are not saving customizations in your init file then you are supposed to load `custom.el` at the end of your init file. See [Saving Customizations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Customizations.html) in the Emacs manual (available at your local Emacs with `C-h i g(emacs)Saving customizations`)

Comment: @NickD part of the config documentation in Doom Emacs says "Note: do not use M-x customize or the customize API in general. Doom is designed to be configured programmatically from your config.el, which can conflict with Customize’s way of modifying variables." I am not sure how this should all works. https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/docs/getting_started.org#configure

Comment: Try it in any case: this is not *you* using customize, but Org mode itself. If it doesn't work, then there is an incompatibility between Doom and Org mode. But I suspect that they are being overcautious and that it is going to work.

Comment: @NickD yeah, i did try it. custom.el is in fact being written correctly. It's just not being read on startup.

Comment: Did you try  loading from your config.el the way the manual suggests?

Comment: @NickD yes. I think the problem might be deeper. I am going to do another update, and see if that fixes it.